# Bake mesh not clickable

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to make a fountain and I have finished the fluid baking...Now I want to bake the mesh it doesn't allow me to bake it.

I have to bake it in the domain
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this is not resumable data. Click on the button near the cache [image]. Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you :) then I press bake all right?

Comment: Yes, then you press "bake".