# Unable to Bake Mesh? How to fix this?

Tags: baking

I'm pretty new to Blender and I was trying out the fluid simulations and when it came to baking the mesh, I wasn't able to do it and I am kind of confused as to what the problem is as I have never baked before in Blender. I'd appreciate if y'all could lend me a hand and let me know what I have done wrong and how to fix it. At the moment, the Bake Mesh button just seems to be greyed out and clicking on it does nothing, the other baking options are working I think. I have already managed to bake the data, it's just the mesh which needs to be done but the button is preventing it. I have unbaked the data until I can figure out what is causing the problem. I have attached images of all of my settings which I have changed in the fluid settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Expand the properties area and find out what it’s saying about a “non-resumable cache“

Comment: I managed to fix it now, I discovered a thread similar to my issue and it fixed it. The thread was this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218360/bake-mesh-not-clickable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bake mesh not clickable](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218360/bake-mesh-not-clickable)

Comment: Yes, this thread answered my question and I was able to resolve the issue. Sorry for the late reply, I forgot to check but, I'm all ears if you had a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the "is resumable" checkbox under your cache settings (you can see it in your last picture of your question).

Blender can cache calculations which can take a long time to produce. But it does this not always automatically.

By clicking this checkbox you tell Blender to use the cache.